# Proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n[\log (n+1)-\log(n)]=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Can someone explain me why $\lim_{n \to \infty} n[\log (n+1)-\log(n)]=1$? Isn't that an indeterminate form? I mean, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} [\log (n+1)-\log(n)] = 0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n=0 \cdot\infty$?

I'm just starting with sequences, and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative without L'Hopital, but rather using the very well known limit:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\cdot\left(\ln(n+1) - \ln n\right)\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right) \\ 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\\ 
&= \ln \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\ 
&= \ln e \\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$

I'm assuming you used $\log x$ for $\log_ex$ or simply $\ln x$.

Answer (score 5):

It's because it can rewritten as 
$$n\log\frac{n+1}n=n\log\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)=\frac{\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)}{\dfrac1n}$$
Set $u=\dfrac1n$. This expression becomes $\dfrac{\log(1+u)}u$, and it is standard from high school that the limit of this quotient as $u\to 0$ is$\;\bigl(\log(1+u)\bigr)'_{u=0},\:$ i.e. $\:1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the rule of L'Hopital, the calculation could go as follows
\begin{align*}
L
:= \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \log \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)}{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{align*}
(here I am only using logarithm and fraction properties).

Now this in an indeterminate form ''$\frac{0}{0}$'', so we can apply the above mentioned rule by differentiating the numerator and the denominator:
\begin{align*}
L
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{n + 1} \left( \frac{1}{n} -\frac{n + 1}{n^2} \right)}{- \frac{1}{n^2}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n + 1}
= 1.
\end{align*}
This follows because
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x}
= \frac{d}{dx} x^{-1}
= - x^{-2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx} \log\left(\frac{x + 1}{x} \right)
= \frac{d}{dx} \log(x + 1) - \frac{d}{dx} \log(x)
= \frac{1}{x + 1} - \frac{1}{x}
= \frac{x}{x + 1} \left( \frac{1}{x} -\frac{x + 1}{x^2} \right).
\end{equation*}
Here, we can view $n \mapsto n \log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$ as a function on $(0, \infty)$, so differentiation makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You could even go beyond the limit. Write
$$a_n= n[\log (n+1)-\log(n)]=n \log\left(\frac{n+1}n \right)=n \log\left(1+\frac{1}n \right)$$
Now, remembering that for small $x$
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ make $x=\frac 1 n$ to get
$$a_n=n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Just try it for $n=10$. You will get
$$a_{10}=10 \,\log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)\approx 0.953102$$ while the above expansion would give
$$a_{10}\simeq \frac{143}{150}\approx 0.953333$$

Comment: (+1) beyond the limit!