# $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right )$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

> Compute the following limit: $$\Large \lim_{n\to\infty} n\log \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right ).$$

**My solution.**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\\color{red}{=}\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)\\=\log(e)\\=1$$

In the red equality I used the fact that $\log(n)$ is continuous in $n=e$.

Is my solution correct? Are there any other ways to determine this limit?

Comment: It's fine, but don't talk about $\log(n),$ talk about $\log(x).$ The variable $n$ is (1) already in use in the question, and $(2)$ usually is interpreted as an integer, while your statement relies on $\log(x)$ where $x$ is close to $e.$ It's not technically wrong, just a risk of communication errors in problems like this.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050740/proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-log-n1-logn-1), for example. Apply L'Hospital on $L
:= \lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \log \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \left( \frac{n + 1}{n} \right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm too much of a purist but saying all these $\lim$s when the limit is not known/shown to exist beforehand seems iffy. However everything is correct if you overlook that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The OP is studying the limit of a sequence, and you cannot just apply Hôpital Theorem like this to sequences in general, and to $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ in particular. Any Theorem possesses a series of hypotheses that must be satisfied to be able to apply it; this one requires that we are studying the ratio between two differentiable functions: here we have *sequences*, which are not differentiable for $(1)$ diff. is defined only at internal points of the domain and $(2)$ $\mathbb{N}$ does not posses internal points. An ausiliary function must be introduced to apply the Theorem.

Comment: @EnricoM. Yes, sure. So introduce an auxiliary function, I agree with it. The duplicate has other solutions, by the way. So there is no need to use L'Hospital.

Comment: @DietrichBurde :) (Sorry, I did not want to be obnoxious, just to put some clarification for the OP. It will may be useful for him in the future).

Comment: @EnricoM. No problem, I understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n[\log (n+1)-\log(n)]=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050740/proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-log-n1-logn-1)

Comment: Note regarding my edit: in mathematics, we evaluate (not "solve") expressions and solve equations.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to use the series expansion of $\log(1+x)$. $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{n\log\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{n\log\left(1 + \frac {1}{n}\right)}$$ $$= \lim_{n\to \infty}{n\left(\frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)} = 1$$